# How to calculate automatically the sum in the graph that will be added new rows?

Tags: excel, vba

When I click the button of the user form, the new row(Row7) will be added exactly under the graph(A2:E6), then goes again and again.

On the columns G, if column b is Debit Quantity * Rate will be sown, and if Credit it will be - value.

=IF(B2="Debit",-D2*E2,D2*E2)

In this case, column G7 should be filled by 144(D7*E7) automatically.

・What I want to do is that

When I click the button, Column G will also calculate automatically, not click the lower right and pull every time.

Is that possible to do it inside the Excel sheet? Or Set as a click event?

To be safe, I also put the click event codes below the photo

[image: photo1]

```html
Public Sub btnAddtransaction_Click()
MsgBox "Example"
Dim newTransaction As New Transaction

newTransaction.TransactionDate = Now()
newTransaction.CryptCurrency = cmBoxCurrency.Value
newTransaction.Quantity = txtboxQuantity.Value
newTransaction.ExchangeRate = txtboxExchangerate.Value

If (optCredit) Then
newTransaction.TransactionType = Credit
End If
If (optDebit) Then
newTransaction.TransactionType = Debit
End If

save2 newTransaction

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we set this as a table?

Highlight Contiguous Area to be set as table - insert tab - table

Adding a New Row will bring formula with it

[image]